# Appending the Sum of the Number of Rows Present

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my code:

```
def dictListSum(dictionary):
    temporary_list = []
    final_list = []

    for (key, value) in sorted(dictionary.items()):
        temporary_list.append(value[0:])

    nRows = len(temporary_list)
    nCols = len(temporary_list[0])

    for row in range(0, nRows-1):
        for col in range(0, nCols):
            final_list.append(temporary_list[row][col] + temporary_list[row + 1][col])

    return final_list
```

I'm having issues dealing with this line:

```
final_list.append(temporary_list[row][col] + temporary_list[row + 1][col])
```

Here's the format I would expect from the user's dictionary input:

```
a = {'A': [3, 11, 2], 'B': [5, 2, 0]}
```

Now, the code runs just fine if the user's dictionary has only two keys. The problem for me starts to occur when the users inputs something like this:

```
a = {'A':[4, 5, 2, 5, 6, 3], 'B': [4, 5, 6, 2, 4, 6], 'C': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,], 'D': [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]}
```

If this was the case, my troublesome line of code would have to look like this:

```
final_list.append(temporary_list[row][col] + temporary_list[row + 1][col] temporary_list[row + 2][col] temporary_list[row + 3][col])
```

So, how would I be able to add all the rows (lists present) together in a sequential format? **Keep in mind that the user gets to create as many keys as he/she wants, provided they are of the same length and are in a list format.**

An example output that would be wrong (using the latter dictionary):

```
a = {'A':[4, 5, 2, 5, 6, 3], 'B': [4, 5, 6, 2, 4, 6], 'C': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,], 'D': [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]}
dictListSum(a)

[8, 10, 8, 7, 10, 9, 5, 6, 7, 3, 5, 7, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

What should happen:

```
dictListSum(a)

[11, 13, 11, 10, 13, 12]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to think about this: view the values of your dictionary as the rows of a table, and then sum along the columns. i.e. convert this:

```
[4, 5, 2, 5, 6, 3],
[4, 5, 6, 2, 4, 6],
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

to this:

```
[4, 4, 1, 2],
[5, 5, 1, 2],
[6, 2, 1, 2],
[2, 5, 1, 2],
[4, 6, 1, 2],
[6, 3, 1, 2]
```

...and then sum the lists. To achieve that:

```
[sum(lst) for lst in zip(*a.values())]
```

[`zip(*lists)`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#zip) is a pattern that is basically equivalent to "transposing" a "matrix"; then, we just sum along each of the "rows" (`lst`).

Comment: The zip(*iterables) function--this fixed my issue perfectly. Though, I must ask: Is there a way to do what you posted as your answer in a sequential format (for my original code), or would that require that my original function have a set value for the amount of keys that are allowed?

Comment: @TZK203 I'm not sure what you mean by "sequential". Do you mean something like [the reference implementation of `zip` given in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#zip)?

Comment: Here is an example of what I would have intended.

So, assuming there must be at least 2 key values:

If there are 2 key values:

    (temporary_list[row][col] + temporary_list[row+1][col])

If 3 key values:

   (temporary_list[row][col] + temporary_list[row+1][col] + temporary_list[row+2][col])

And so on.

Comment: @TZK203 I mean, you could just put it in a for loop - create a temporary variable `temp = 0`, and then `for i in range(len(temporary_list)): temp += temporary_list[row+i][col]`.